# Xamarin Forms - Open Location Permission page of app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, location

i am using Xamarin forms and want to open following **Location permissio**n page of my app. It would be great help if someone can suggest I need this screen in both #IOS & #Android using #xamarinforms.
Thanks in adavnce.
[image]

Comment: permissions dialogs/prompts are generated by the OS, not the app

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, we could not customize the permission dialogs. It would show the default one.

Quote from: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-request

> Your app cannot customize the dialog that appears when you call requestPermissions()